# Why are Excel macro dangerous?

Tags: microsoft-excel, security

Can someone explain me why Microsoft Excel 2012 is telling me that accepting automatically every macros is dangerous, I mean how can they be dangerous, for my worksheets, for my entire computer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel macros are written VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). Those scripts can (potentially) gain access to your operating system, and file system: deleting files, uploading data, downloading spyware etc. That's why you have to be sure you trust the script source before allowing it to run.

Answer (score 2):

Macros written with malicious intent could harm your computer, the same way any malware could.

[Here's](http://www.bc.edu/offices/help/security/virus/macrovirus.html) an article from Boston College on the subject.
From the article:

> ABOUT MACROS AND MACRO VIRUSES
>
> A macro is a series of program commands
> or instructions designed to simplify repetitive tasks within a program
> in the Microsoft Office suite (such as Microsoft Word, Excel,
> PowerPoint, etc.). Any operating system can receive a macro virus,
> even Macs, as long as you have Microsoft Office installed on it. A
> macro virus is a virus that is created by using the built-in macro
> programming language, designed to execute as soon as the file is
> opened. It attaches itself to a document file and waits until an
> application like Microsoft Word opens it.